# Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1' for a mysql db running in a local Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I am trying to connect to a mysql instance running inside a local Docker Container, but I am getting a

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.17.0.1'`

I initialized the container by running:

```
docker image pull mariadb:10.4
docker run --name mariadbtest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=user -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=localhost -p 3306:3306 -d docker.io/library/mariadb:10.4
```

When I try to connect to the db using `mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u root -p` from the host machine, I get the error mentioned in the title. I am able to use the same command to connect as a user that was initialized in the command that started the Docker container (`mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=TCP -u user -p`) successfully.

I have verified that I can connect to the db from inside the Docker container itself after running `docker exec -it mariadbtest bash` and `mysql -u root -p`.

I'd appreciate any insights into what's happening.

Comment: `SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user` and what do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=localhost` should be left out, which then it defaults to `%` else its not going to match `172.17.0.1`

Comment: That did it. Thank you, I'll dig into what the MYSQL_ROOT_HOST env variable does that caused this.

Comment: np, yeah its noted in the image docs https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb (search MYSQL_ROOT_HOST), don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem with a similar root. I couldn't connect to the 172.17.0.1 IP address of my host.

The solution was that I switched to its 192.168.1.110 address and it started to work.

The reason seems to be caused by an old docker issue: https://forums.docker.com/t/connection-refused-when-you-try-to-connect-to-a-service-port-started-on-host/11508

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 1. CREATE USER 'root'@'172.17.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_PASSWORD'; 
 2. GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'root'@'172.17.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 3. flush privileges;
```

then login